# How do you find the power of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example with $5^x=125$. How do you manipulate the equation to find $x$?

Comment: In this case you are probably expected to *recognize* that $5^3=125$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have: 
$$5^x = 125$$
$$\log(5^x) = \log(125)$$
$$x\log(5) = \log(125)$$
$$x = \frac{\log(125)}{\log(5)}$$
Can you guess the answer ?

Comment: oh yeah, thank you. just fixed it

Comment: Knew the answer, just used a simple example

Answer (score 0):

By taking logarithm for both sides, we should have: 
$$\log (5^x)  = \log(125)$$

one of the main properties of logarithm functions is that you can take the power out of the logarithm, so we would have:

$$x \log(5) = \log(125)$$

solve for $x$ and you're done..

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution: $$\begin{aligned}5^x&=125\\ {5^x}/5&={125}/5\\ 5^{x-1}&=25\\ {5^{x-1}}/5&=5\\ 5^{x-2}&=5\\ \end{aligned}$$  We can conclude that $x-2=1 \implies x=3$.

Comment: One is one of those so-called special cases. :)

Comment: 125/5 = 25 @Jasha

Comment: I've suggested an edit.. @Jasha